# Send email when a new post is published

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, email, notifications

I'm looking for a method, or plugin, that will allow me to do the following:

1. User can signup to a 'notifications' email list
2. When a new post is published on the site, users on this list are automatically emailed a notification

This is for site visitors as opposed to administrators or registered users.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://wordpress.org/plugins/email-posts-to-subscribers/) is good plugin for this requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it yet, but you can accomplish this with [Jetpack](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/jetpack/), which is made (at least partially) by the founders of WordPress.

The advantage is that it uses the Wordpress.com servers to handle the outgoing mail. This is a big plus because shared servers have throttling limits that only allow you to send a certain amount of e-mails in a given time frame (usually an hour). You don't have to worry about the IP of your own servers ending up blacklisted if anyone marks the e-mails as spam instead of unsubscribing.

Check it out, there are other features to it as well.

Answer (score 3):

Right now I'm using [Subscribe2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/subscribe2/) WordPress plugin to manage all subscription, I found this plugin simple, neat and easy to use, also the plugin has good review/ratings over Wordpress Plugins directory.

Answer (score 1):

Feedburner is the best because you also gets analytics. Connects to any gmail account via feedburner.google.com. On the Subscribe tab you can get the code for Email subscriptions. Just stick that into a Text widget.

Comment: I think it is risky to rely on a Google API. They are all taken down after some time.